# Игнорируется условие в C++

Tags: c++, if

Выполняю дз: в задании необходимо произвести вычисление `y` согласно одной из формул в зависимости от условия, однако после перепроверки вручную я увидел, что вычисления всегда проходят по первой части условия, игнорируя `else if`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    float x, a, y;
    cout << "Введите x, a" << endl;
    cin >> x >> a;
    if (0 <= x <= 2)
        if (x + a > 0) y = a + log(x + a);
        else
        {
            cout << "ln не вычисляется" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    else if (x > 2) y = sqrt(abs(sin(a * x)));
        else y = x * x - cos(a);
    
    cout << "При x=" << x << " a=" << a << " получаем y=" << y << endl;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само собой.

```
0 <= x <= 2
```

означает

```
(0 <= x) <= 2
```

Поскольку если условие верно, то `(0 <= x)` превращается в 1 (true), если неверно — в 0 (false), а и то, и другое меньше 2 — условие всегда истинно...

То, что вы хотите, надо записывать как

```
0 <= x && x <= 2
```

что с учетом приоритета операторов выполняется как

```
(0 <= x) && (x <= 2)
```

и означает "*x больше или равен 0 **И** x меньше или равен 2*"...

Comment: Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы объяснить, что означает запись x && x?

Comment: @Blamy, ничего полезного, поэтому тут её и нет. Смотри приоритеты операторов.

Comment: @Qwertiy: думаю, ТС ещё не дочитал до булевых операторов

Comment: 8-/ вот уж не ожидал, что это можно ***так*** воспринять...

Comment: "Само собой"? В Питоне двойные неравенства обрабатываются ожидаемым образом.